# Jabber-Net release build fails to connect to XMPP Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xmpp

I downloaded jabber-net source from http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/. Open the .sln file (2005-jabber-net.sln) in VS 2005/08, set "2005-Example" as active project, build it in Debug mode, connect to a XMPP Server, after connect() method is called, the callback jc_OnAuthenticate() gets called which means the application is connected to XMPP Server.

---

Then i build the .sln in Release Mode, ran the same example again, this time after connect() call nothing happens, the callback jc_OnAuthenticate() doesn't get called ever. Is it a known issue with jabber-net?

Comment: How do you see when `jc_OnAuthenticate()` is called?  I hope you are not trying with the debugger.

Comment: There is "MessageBox.Show("Connected");" written in jc_OnAuthenticate(). I see it in debug build but not in release build.

Comment: I do plan to use Matrix(http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/)

Answer (score 3):

There is some code in Debug.Assert statements such as:

\jabber\protocol\EnumParser.cs(184):

```
Debug.Assert(map.TryGetValue(value, out val));
```

I rewrote to:

```
bool b = map.TryGetValue(value, out val);
Debug.Assert(b);
```

Works (at least for me).